# Почему не отображается картинка?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Реализовал `RecyclerView`

Вроде все сделал правильно, и есть список от куда брать данные и шаблон и адаптер и проверяю на дебагере все ок, но на устройстве ничего нет... Как будто бы `invisible` стоит... не пойму в чем дело...

Вот код XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/backforchat"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".activities.ActivityChat">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarchat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/color_grew_toolbar"
            android:elevation="2dp">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvChat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Вот код адаптера

```
public class ChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ChatAdapter.ChatHolder> {

private List<MessagesChat> messages;

public ChatAdapter(List<MessagesChat> messages) {
    this.messages = messages;
}

@Override
public ChatHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.message_card, viewGroup, false);
    return new ChatHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ChatHolder holder, int i) {
    MessagesChat messagesChat = messages.get(i);

    Bitmap bitmap = messagesChat.getPersonPhotoChat();
    if (bitmap != null) {
        holder.ivPersonPhotoChat.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        holder.ivPersonPhotoChat.setImageResource(States.DEFAULT_PHOTO_ICON);
    }

    holder.tvMessageBody.setText(messagesChat.getMessageBody());
    holder.tvArriveTime.setText(messagesChat.getArrivingTime());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return messages.size();
}

class ChatHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    ImageView ivPersonPhotoChat;
    TextView tvMessageBody;
    TextView tvArriveTime;

    public ChatHolder(View item) {
        super(item);
        ivPersonPhotoChat = (ImageView) item.findViewById(R.id.ivPersonPhotoChat);
        tvMessageBody = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvMessageBody);
        tvArriveTime = (TextView) item.findViewById(R.id.tvArriveTime);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
}
}
```

и вот сам класс

```
public class ActivityChat extends AppCompatActivity {

private Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_chat);

    context = getApplicationContext();
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarchat);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    List<MessagesChat> messages = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++){
        messages.add(new MessagesChat("Hello!", "14:24", null));
    }

    RecyclerView rvChat = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvChat);
    ChatAdapter adapter = new ChatAdapter(messages);
    rvChat.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Что пропустил? Или как можно проверить?

В классе список наполняется и передается адаптеру это видно по дебагу, адаптер его принимает, все норм... Почему нет картинки на экране не пойму...

Comment: Нет только картинки? В коде нет никаких отсылок к картинкам в данных, откуда она должна появиться

Comment: @pavlofff в смысле нет отсылок? Может мы не про одно и тоже говорим, я имею ввиду - нет картинки , в том смысле, что на экране не появляется список... Только пустой бекграунд который я установил в XML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно добавить какой-нибудь LayoutManager. Например, Linear:

```
rvChat.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
rvChat.setAdapter(adapter);
```